# Ionic 2 - Check Internet Connection on each request

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I´m developping an app on Ionic 2 and I want to check internet connection for each request, i.e., I want to receive an instant message each time network is down or up.

My simple project will have :
page 1 - home (button to go to another page)
page 2 - another page

For that I´m using cordova plugin network information. From ionic 2 documentation:

```
import {Network, Connection} from 'ionic-native';

// watch network for a disconnect
let disconnectSubscription = Network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network was disconnected :-( ')
});

// stop disconnect watch
disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();


// watch network for a connection
let connectSubscription = Network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network connected!');    
  // We just got a connection but we need to wait briefly
    // before we determine the connection type.  Might need to wait    
  // prior to doing any api requests as well.
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(Network.connection);
    if (Network.connection === Connection.WIFI) {
      console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
    }
  }, 3000);
});

// stop connect watch
connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

The problem is that Network.onConnect().subscribe(() do not retrieve anything. It is the best way yo accomplish my goal?

Comment: Just as a comment, not an answer at all, I don't think the network plugin is really reliable for this kind of detection, since your user may actually be connected to a router that has no connection and only because there is a wifi link active, the plugin will indicate that there is a valid connection. I am working in a solution to this as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you are calling the unsubscribe method after you have subscribed for network changes. If you call `connectSubscription.unsubscribe()` you are telling ionic that now you don't care about changes in the network connection state. Remove the 2 unsubscribe methods and your code should be fine.

Also the subscribe and unsubscribe methods only listen for changes so to check for connectivity, use the comparison code directly.

```
if (Network.connection === 'wifi') {
    // do some api work
}
```

Let me know if it works.